# Overflow Widgets in that rounded corners QFrame

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qframe

I have a problem with QFrame, when i setStyleSheet of QFrame like this;

```py
frame = QFrame(self.window)
frame.setObjectName('Custom_Widget')
frame.setStyleSheet("""
   #Custom_Widget {
     background: #002025;
     border-radius: 20px;
     opacity: 100;
     border: 2px solid #ff2025;                   
        }""")
```

It's like this;
[image: img1]

You see corners rounded but widget is not rounded. It's rectangle. This is my first problem.My second problem is
[image: img2]
You see QMediaPlayer's corners not rounded because it overflows QWidget. How can i solve this problem?

My all code below;

```py
# PyQt5 Video player
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, Qt, QUrl,QRect, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFileDialog, QHBoxLayout, QLabel,
        QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QSlider, QStyle, QVBoxLayout, QWidget,QProgressBar,QFrame)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QWidget, QPushButton, QAction
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
import sys,os

class VideoWindow(QMainWindow):
    closeSignal = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VideoWindow, self).__init__(parent)

    def setupUi(self,window):
        self.window = window
        self.window.setFixedSize(784,442)
        #self.window.setFixedSize(884,542)
        self.window.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint|Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint|Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)

        widget = QWidget(self.window)

        widget.setObjectName('Custom_Widget')
        widget.setStyleSheet("""
        #Custom_Widget {
            background: #002025;
            border-radius: 20px;
            opacity: 100;
            border: 2px solid #ff2025;
        }
        """)

        videoWidget = QVideoWidget(widget)
        videoWidget.setGeometry(QRect(0,0,784, 442))

        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.getcwd() + "\\logo-anim.avi")))
        self.mediaPlayer.play()
        #self.mediaPlayer.stateChanged.connect(lambda x: self.closeSignal.emit(x))
        self.mediaPlayer.stateChanged.connect(lambda x: sys.exit())
        
        self.window.setCentralWidget(widget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QMainWindow()
    player = VideoWindow()
    player.setFixedSize(784, 442)
    player.setupUi(w)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues and misconceptions in your code, which is also very confusing.

- you are creating a QMainWindow (`VideoWindow`) which you're not using.
- you are adding the video widget as a child of a QWidget, and setting the same geometry for the QMainWindow, the QWidget and the QVideoWidget; how would you expect to have a border, if they all have the same geometry?
- if you want a plain widget with borders and without other features, using a QMainWindow is not only unnecessary, but also wrong: QMainWindows provide features like an internal layout, support for status bars, toolbars, dock widgets and menus, which you clearly are not going to use; a QWidget is what is going to be used instead.
- if a widget is going to have children, fixed geometries should be avoided, while layout managers should always be used instead, even if there's only *one* widget;
- setting rounded borders through stylesheets doesn't change the actual shape of the widget (which is *always* rectangular), and you need to apply a *mask* instead.
- you're trying to use a [`Qt.WidgetAttribute`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) for window flags, which is not only very wrong, but also causes some issues as it's not a window flag; such attributes must be used with [`setAttribute()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setAttribute).
- setting the frameless flag will probably prevent moving the window in most systems, you should address that by providing appropriate mouse interaction.
- it's usually better to set a parent for new Qt objects (unless they're widgets), especially when they use threaded/concurrent processing (like QMediaPlayer), so they will be properly removed when the parent is, and system resources are correctly released.

This is a revision of your code.

```
class VideoWindow(QWidget):
    closeSignal = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VideoWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setFixedSize(784,442)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint|Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        self.setStyleSheet("""
        VideoWindow {
            background: #002025;
            border-radius: 20px;
            opacity: 100;
            border: 2px solid #ff2025;
        }
        """)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        videoWidget = QVideoWidget()
        layout.addWidget(videoWidget)

        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(self, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.getcwd() + "/test.mp4")))
        self.mediaPlayer.play()

        self.startPos = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.startPos = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.startPos:
            self.move(self.pos() + (event.pos() - self.startPos))

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.startPos = None

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(QRectF(self.rect()), 20, 20)
        reg = QRegion(path.toFillPolygon().toPolygon())
        self.setMask(reg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = VideoWindow()
    player.setFixedSize(784, 442)
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I thought that the actions I applied to QWidget would reflect on QMediaPlayer when they overlap. I guess that's how I cropped the code from different websites :) Actually I just started using PyQt5 and I want create a splash screen for my application. I didn't know I had so many mistakes, thank you so much for your help. Finally, is there any resource you could recommend to learn PyQt5?

Comment: There are plenty of resources, and their target mostly depends on programming knowledge and experience, so only you know what's best. Note that QMediaPlayer is inteded to display multimedia contents, which is usually not the aim of a splash screen, consider exporting the video as a GIF and load a QMovie instead: it uses less resources, loads faster and it's more suited for this case. Also remember that there's the QSplashScreen class (which must be properly subclassed in order to correctly show smooth animations)

Comment: Ok, thanks for everything. I will try your suggestions.